# Socket can't connect to ip address specified in the ServerSocket. (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android

ServerSocket Java class:

```
public class Server{
private static ServerSocket server;
public static int PORT = 9000;
public static int maxSockets = 10;
private static int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
public static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cores +1);
public static String hostserver_dataFile = "../data/data.csv";
public static String positions_dataFile = "../data/positions.csv";
public static String usernames_dataFile = "../data/usernames.csv";

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Server starting...\n");
    try {
        InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.137.1")
        server = new ServerSocket(PORT,maxSockets,ip);
        while(true){ 
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(hostserver_dataFile));

        Socket s = server.accept();
        //write to socket
        ObjectOutputStream s_out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        //read from socket
        ObjectInputStream s_in = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
       
    

        String message = (String) s_in.readObject();
        String[] new_message =message.split(",");
        System.out.println("User joined. Id:" + new_message[1]);

        handleRequest(new_message,s,s_out,s_in);
        
        }
        
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}

public static void handleRequest(String[] request,Socket s,ObjectOutputStream s_out,ObjectInputStream s_in ) {
        switch(request[0]){
            case "GET HOST DATA":
                sendData(s,s_out,hostserver_dataFile);
                break;
            case "GET POSITION DATA":
                sendData(s,s_out,positions_dataFile);
                break;
            case "GET USERNAME":
                sendData(s,s_out,hostserver_dataFile);
                break;
            case "POST USERNAME":
                storeUsername(request, usernames_dataFile);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        
        }
}
public static void sendData(Socket s,ObjectOutputStream out,String file_toRead) {
    executor.execute(()-> {
        try {
        
            ObjectOutputStream s_out = out;
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file_toRead));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while(line != null) {
                String toSend = "";
                String[] row = line.split(",");
                for(String val : row ) {
                    toSend += val +" ";
                }
                s_out.writeObject(toSend);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            s_out.close();
            reader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}

public static void storeUsername(String[] data,String file_toWrite) {
    executor.execute(()-> {
        boolean data_exists = false;
        boolean override = false;
        boolean username_given = false;
        try {
            String id = data[1];
            String new_userName = data[2];
            String old_userName= "";

            
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file_toWrite));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while(line != null){
                buffer.append(line + System.lineSeparator());
                String[] row = line.split(",");
                if(row[1].equals(new_userName) && !id.equals(row[0]))
                   username_given = true;
                if(row[0].equals(id)) //id is in the csv file
                    if(row[1].equals(new_userName)){ //data exists already
                        data_exists = true;
                    }else { //override data
                        old_userName= row[1];
                        override = true;
                    }
                
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            reader.close(); 

            if(!data_exists && !username_given ){
                if(override) {
                    FileWriter csvWriter = new FileWriter(file_toWrite,false);
                    String fileContent = buffer.toString();
                    fileContent.replaceAll(old_userName,new_userName);
                    csvWriter.append(fileContent);
                    csvWriter.flush();
                    csvWriter.close();

                }else {
                    FileWriter csvWriter = new FileWriter(file_toWrite,true);
                    csvWriter.append(String.join(",",data));
                    csvWriter.append("\n");
                    csvWriter.flush();
                    csvWriter.close();
                }
            }
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Client connection in Android:

```
package com.example.myapplication.Util;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class BackgroundTasks {
    private static int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    public static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cores);

    //stop all threads and release resources
    public void shutdown() {
        executor.shutdown();
    }

    public List<String> getRequest(String id, String typeData){
            Future<List<String>> result = executor.submit(() -> {

                    Socket s = null;
                    try {
                        List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
                        System.out.println("Attempting to connect to server..");
                        s = new Socket(Configuration.Server, Configuration.Port);
                        System.out.println(s.isConnected());
                        //reader and writer
                        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

                        out.writeObject(typeData + "," + id);
                        String line = in.readLine();

                        while (line != null) {
                            System.out.println(line);
                            res.add(line);
                            line = in.readLine();
                        }
                        s.close();
                        return res;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println("Connection failed!");
                        return null;
                    }
                });

            try {
                return result.get();
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Cant get result");
                return null;
            }
     }

     public void setUserName(String id, String userName) {
         executor.execute(() ->{
             Socket s = null;
             try {
                 List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
                 s = new Socket(Configuration.Server, Configuration.Port);
                 //reader and writer
                 ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

                 out.writeObject(Requests.setUserName + "," + id + "," + userName);

                 s.close();
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         });
     }


     public String getUserName(String id) {
             List<String> result = getRequest(id,Requests.UserName);
             return result.get(0);
     }

}
```

Configuration Class:

```
public class Configuration{
    public static String Server = "192.168.137.1";
    public static int Port = 9000;
}
```

As i start the application and try to host a game, a connection should be established and the server should tell each player who is in the host server as well as it reads a csv file with the names of each player who connected to the server. I receive this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlUS9.png) as i try to execude the following code:

```
public class HostingGameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hosting_game);

        FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

       // TextView players_counter_text = findViewById(R.id.player_counter_text);
      //  TextView players_display_text = findViewById(R.id.players_display_text);
        BackgroundTasks taskExecutor = new BackgroundTasks();
        Button startGame_button = findViewById(R.id.startGame_button);
        startGame_button.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.GRAY));

      //  String userName = taskExecutor.getUserName(mAuth.getUid());
        List<String> host_data_request;
        host_data_request = taskExecutor.getRequest(mAuth.getUid(), Requests.Host_Data);
       // updateText(host_data_request);
        taskExecutor.shutdown();

    }

    void updateText(List<String> host_data_request) {
        BackgroundTasks.executor.execute(()-> {
            TextView players_display_text = findViewById(R.id.players_display_text);
            StringBuilder buffer =new StringBuilder();
            for(String playerName : host_data_request) {
                String[] row_values = playerName.split(" ");
                buffer.append(row_values[1]).append("\n");
            }
            String curr_text = players_display_text.getText().toString();
            buffer.insert(0,curr_text).insert(1,"\n");
            players_display_text.setText(buffer.toString());
        });

    }
}
```

There is a TextView object and i try to set the text to the appropriate names of the players.

I try to connect to the ip from another device which is connected via hotspot to the device which runs the server.
If i use only one device and change the ip to my local ip4 -> the code works. However if i try to connect to the ip on a different device, no connection can be astablished, as if the ip doesn't exist.

Any suggestions would help me a lot.

Comment: `ip address specified in the ServerSocket` I see no ip address specified.

Comment: - Make sure you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
` in Manifest.xml. because an EPERM (Operation not permitted) will raise

- Make sure that server and android are connected to same network/router since currently you are using private ip addresses (192.168...)

Comment: Please put all info in your post and remove those comments. Write a readable post to begin with.

Comment: `server = new ServerSocket(PORT);` Keep that! Dont mess around with ip's for a server socket. The ip is for the client only.

Comment: why what would be the problem ? Every time i connect to my Network the ip that the server uses changes. Wouldn't that mean i need to change the Client ip every time i connect to my network ?